# How to instantiate Java enum

Tags: java

```
public enum Difficulty {
EASY,   //easy game, lots of villages to spare
NORMAL, //normal game, fewer villagers & bullets
HARD;   //hard game, the wolf relocates when shot

/**
 * Returns a multi-line String describing the characteristics of this
 * difficulty level.
 */
public String toString() {
    return "Player starts in the village: " + getPlayerStartsInVillage() +
            "\nNumber of villagers: " + getVillagerCount() +
            "\nAvailable silver bullets: " + getSilverBulletCount() + 
            "\nWerewolf moves when shot: " + getWolfMovesWhenShot();
}

/**
 * Returns true if the player starts in the same area as the village for
 * this difficulty level, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean getPlayerStartsInVillage() {
    return this == EASY;
}

/**
 * Returns the initial number of villagers for this difficulty level.
 */
public int getVillagerCount() {
    switch (this) {
    case EASY: return 6;
    case NORMAL: return 4;
    default /*HARD*/: return 4;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the number of silver bullets the player starts with in this
 * difficulty level.
 */
public int getSilverBulletCount() {
    switch (this) {
    case EASY: return 8;
    case NORMAL: return 6;
    default /*HARD*/: return 6;
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if the werewolf moves when hit, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean getWolfMovesWhenShot() {
    return this == HARD;
}
```

I have this (above) class which I want to call upon to use its methods in the below but I'm not sure how. I know of

```
Difficulty obj1 = new Difficulty();
```

but that returns with 'cannot instantiate difficulty'. Can someone please show me what code to write to get this to work?

```
public class WereWolfenstein2D {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Difficulty obj1 = Difficulty.EASY`?

Comment: Furthermore don't use `switch` in the methods this way. Add `final` fields to the enum instead and initialize them using a constructor. See planets example here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate enums this way:

```
Difficulty obj1 = new Difficulty();
```

And there's a good reason for that.

Enums are for when you have a fixed set of related constants. You don't want to instantiate one, because then the set would not be fixed.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
Difficulty obj1 = Difficulty.NORMAL
```

Good to read [Oracle Tutorial Java Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)